# How can I infer the UTC offset from an ISO date with date-fns or any other datetime library?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Currently I am doing this:

```
import { parseISO, format } from 'date-fns';
import { formatInTimeZone } from 'date-fns-tz'

// e.g. chosenConnection['departure'] === "2022-08-26T03:41:25.280415+02:00"
departureParsedIso = parseISO(chosenConnection['departure'])
tz = chosenConnection['departure'].slice(-6)
formatInTimeZone(departureParsedIso, tz, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

These departure dates always happen in a certain country and time zone, so of course I need to format the date in the correct time zone, not in the browser's or server's current zone, that's why I'm using `date-fns`' `formatInTimeZone`.

However, I find it really weird and hackish that I have found no other way of extracting the time zone info, i.e. the offset, from `chosenConnection['departure']`. I find it also weird that `departureParsedIso` doesn't hold that information somehow.

Is there a better, more robust, less anti-pattern, more elegant way of doing this? In date-fns? Or maybe with another datetime library?

I have also tried extracting the offset with `format(departureParsedIso, 'xxx')`, but that apparently again returns the client's or server's timezone, and not the time zone encoded in the ISO string. BUT WHY? What is `parseISO` good for, then?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no reliable way to infer a timezone from the offset as a single offset usually aligns to multiple timezones.

Comment: The offset would already be enough!

Answer (score 2):

You can parse a lot of the desired data using [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

In this case using [`DateTime.fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) and setting the `setZone` parameter to true will create a DateTime instance with a *fixed* UTC offset.

This is useful for displaying departure date in local time and also UTC, plus any other zone if necessary (for example CET).

You can also get the UTC offset in minutes, hours and HH:MM.

We can also search for possible IANA zones by looking for any that have the same UTC offset at the time in question. Of course we can see that there will be a large number of possible matches, so without further information we cannot find the exact zone.

So we can get the UTC offset but not necessarily the Timezone from the date.

**NB:** The inferred fixed timezone will not honour any DST changes, so be aware of this when doing any manipulation of the date.

```js
const { DateTime, IANAZone } = luxon;

const departure = "2022-08-26T03:41:25.280415+02:00";
const dt = DateTime.fromISO(departure, { setZone: true });

console.log('Departure (local):', dt.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('Departure (UTC):  ', dt.toUTC().toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('Departure (CET):  ', dt.setZone('CET').toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

console.log('Departure UTC Offset (minutes):', dt.offset);
console.log('Departure UTC Offset (hours):', dt.toFormat('Z'));
console.log('Departure UTC Offset (HH:MM):', dt.toFormat('ZZ'));

console.log('')
const allZones = Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone');
const possibleTimeZones = allZones.map(tz => IANAZone.create(tz)).filter(zone => zone.offset(dt) === dt.offset);
console.log('Possible timezones:', possibleTimeZones.map(zone => zone.zoneName));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-6ZJuab/UnRq1muTChgrVxJhSgygmL2GMLVmSJN7pcBEqJ1dWPbqN9CiZ6U3HrcApTIJsLnMgXYBYgtVkJ8fWiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks promising. I just wonder whether this is really not doable in `date-fns`, since I'm not really keen on switching libraries just yet.

Comment: It might well be, I'm more familiar with luxon, so I've detailed that route in my answer. If you're using date-fns, it's best to stick with that unless you have no other choice!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz#gettimezoneoffset Looks like the best solution at this time. It might not have existing when you posted this question a year ago.

Comment: Thanks, could you add a code snippet please?